# Is it possible to filter my search by distinct tags?

Tags: support, tags, filtering

I know I can use a custom filter to limit searches to questions with `javascript` or `nodejs` tags. However, this might include a mixture with `vuejs` or other tags I'd rather not include. The 'hide' feature is an option, but it still shows the undesired questions just faded out. Can I filter a distinct tag or set of tags? If not, has this been consciously excluded as a feature?

By 'distinct,' I mean if I want to see [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions, I will only see questions with a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag and no other tag. Likewise, if I want [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), I will only see questions with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tags, not questions with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and perhaps some other tag involving a plugin they are using with react and javascript

Comment: Use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1440648

Answer (score 3):

You can use exclude option

```
-[tag]
```

Example:

```
[javascript] or [node.js] -[vue.js]
```

Check the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Well, that's not bad, but it doesn't fully solve the issue. I just gave vue as an example. There are many tags (some of which I don't even know) that I'd like excluded. Therefor, I'd rather there be a 'distinct' feature rather than excluding individual tags one-by-one. Thanks though!

Comment: @silencedogood then I am not sure I understand how you mean by 'distinct'?

Comment: By 'distinct,' I mean if I want to see javascript quesions, I will _only_ see questions with a javascript tag and no other tag. Likewise, if I want javascript and reactjs, I will _only_ see questions with javascript and reactjs tags, not questions with javascript and reactjs and perhaps some other tag involving a plugin they are using with react and javascript.

Comment: @silencedogood ah ok. You could try to raise a feature request. I don't really see how useful that is.. Questions will have all tags it is related to (sometimes even mistagged).