# Best way to convert an old question into a feature request

Tags: discussion

I asked a question (that was more of a feature-request) almost 2 years ago that received positive votes. However, it was my first question on meta and I didn't realize I should have used the `feature-request` tag.

It was recommended I raise a feature request for the issue, but I never did. And I'm not really sure how I'd go about that. I still find myself wanting the feature; should I just post a new question? If I simply add the `feature-request` tag to the post, will it move it up at all in the queue?

I didn't add a link to the OP because I don't want to seem as though I'm trying to direct attention to it...

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389032/is-it-possible-to-filter-my-search-by-distinct-tags)? It was already a feature when you asked it. You are able to filter *out* tags by prepending `-` to them. I'm not sure how you want to convert that question to a feature request, given that it already exists. You need to suggest a new thing that doesn't.

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but as I mentioned in the comments of the question, that's not what I meant by `distinct`. I give a further explanation in the comment that explains why I found the answer insufficient; and thereafter it was recommended I raise a feature-request.

Comment: You mentioned that in the comments of *the answer*. I checked the question and I saw an answer that was relevant for it. I don't expect to need to read all comments to find out information that belongs in the question.

Comment: You can post a question describing clearly what feature you want and why, and tag it feature-request. Whether it's accepted or not is up to the gods.

Comment: At any rate, your suggested filter would be a bad idea. There are ***many*** questions with more than one tag on them, e.g. [[tag:javascript]] [[tag:arrays]] is a pretty common combination. Or [[tag:javascript]] [[tag:ecmascript-6]]. You'd be missing out on those even though they are fundamentally just JS questions.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah... Like I said, I was new and my posts were sometimes poorly done. That's kinda part of the premise behind this post.

Comment: @VLAZ Nevertheless, your opinion of the OP is irrelevant to _this_ post.

Comment: @silencedogood you want to make that into a FR. I'm giving you some more information to think about before you do. I think it's better to be prepared if you're going to do that instead of getting the information afterwards.

Comment: Relevant FAQ, for more specific details on how to write a FR on Meta: [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365)

Comment: @silencedogood - It's never to late to improve a question. Of course like many of mentioned, the feature request, offers little value IMO.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

1. Ask a new Q, properly written and tagged. If you can, delete the old Q.  If you can't delete it, and you think the new Q may be closed as a dup of the old one, reference it and provide a compelling reason why it's not a dup.  If you can't do that, use option 2
2. Edit the old Q into shape and add the required tag(s).  Be careful not to invalidate existing answers.  That will bump it to the front page.

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest you don't bother. The feature you'd be requesting IMHO has little value, the chances of a FR being positively received is low, and the chances of it being implemented even lower.